# Slider with pattern overlay issue

Tags: css, slider

I'm trying to create a slider that fades through images and text. This is simple enough using Flexslider for example, but how do I make it so that the slider has a pattern overlay that is above the image, but **underneath** the text?

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <div id="pattern"></div>
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="slider_text"><span>Some Text<br/>Over the Image</span></div>
            <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="slider_text"><span>Some Text<br/>Over the Image</span></div>
            <img src="http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
        </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H8RKG/)**

In the fiddle I have added the pattern, but it covers the text too ... Is there anyway to do this? I don't really want to have to put the pattern inside every `<li>` either, but so far that's the only solution I can think of.

Thanks!

Comment: [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/H8RKG/1/) - Move the pattern inside the `<ul>` and set the `z-index` on the text higher. (unless I'm blind and that didn't work, its kinda hard to tell)

Comment: @Ruddy WOW, could have sworn I tried this before haha .... I must have missed the z-index or something. THANKS!

Comment: Added it as an answer. And yeah it happens, also no problem! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we move the pattern into the `ul` and set the text's `z-index` higher.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/H8RKG/1/)

The code I added to clearly show whats going on.

### CSS:

```
.slider_text {
    z-index: 999;
}
```

So we move the `#pattern` inside the `ul`.

### HTML:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <div id="pattern"></div>
```

Comment: For anyone who looks for this solution in the future - I found that using the javascript version 2.2.0 of Flexslider stopped this solution from working ... for whatever reason, but reverting to V2 (as used in the DEMO's) it worked fine.